# Is there any way to make whey powder at home?

Tags: baking, substitutions, bread, milk

Any way to make it.Whey powder is pretty expensive here and I want to use it for baking.

Comment: Megh, if you do a Google search you will find tons of information on how to make whey and other protein powders at home.

Comment: i did,but no avail.

Comment: Here, try this: https://www.google.com/search?q=whey+powder+homemade&ei=YK8aVartDMjyoASVpILAAQ

Comment: No reason you couldn't build a cyclone dryer at home: https://www.google.com/search?q=cyclone+dryer&num=20&safe=off&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjl1cjrlevTAhVLxoMKHZCkB_wQ7AkITg&biw=1287&bih=725#imgrc=ii5gimNI0CtYxM: But it's going to cost you a few thousand $ and take more than a weekend or two. Freeze drying (lyophilization) is a lot slower and a lot more energy intensive. If you live in the lower latitudes, you might get away with using shallow trays in the sun, like a salt refinery.

Answer (score 2):

If you really do mean turning liquid whey into a powder, then the answer is "no" unless your have access to some specialised equipment. You need a membrane filter, ultra-filtration to be precise, to concentrate the protein to a syrup with about 70-75% water. You will also need a dryer of one type or another to remove most of that water, spray drying gets you a powder, or you can freeze dry and mill the dried cake into powder. Both membrane filters and dryers do exist in lab-bench scale and therefore it is entirely feasible to install them at home.

Comment: Ultra-filtration membranes love to clog when you get protein concentrations that high. Still, with some backflushing it might be doable. I've never actually tried whey proteins. Perhaps they're not very sticky.

Comment: They do need wash cycles. Type of membrane is important other than just pore size. Proteins are finicky things since they are always shape changing.